# iOS 7 UIWebView clear cache does not work

Tags: ios, caching, uiwebview, ios7

In my project I use UIWebView and after some time I should clear cache. I use this code to do clearing:

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

But in iOS 7 this code doesn't work (in earlier versions everything is OK). It seems, that cached page still loads. For testing cache I use [this page](http://www.lagado.com/tools/cache-test).
And another issue is when I use cache policy. It doesn't work too:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
    [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.lagado.com/tools/cache-test"] 
    cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:30.0];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

This code also always uses cached page.

Does anyone have any ideas about this? Thanks for any help!

Comment: I remember having problems with `NSURLRequest` cache policies starting from iOS 6. I opened a bug with Apple that was marked as 'duplicate' and I never saw it being resolved. You may want to open a bug report with Apple, although I doubt you'll have much luck.